# Is it achievable to merge nested JSONB fields with a JOIN-like statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, join, merge, jsonb

Given this tables:

BOOKS

```
 id | data
----+-------------------------------------------------------
 1  | { title: 'Book 1', price: 10.5, author: { id: 2 } }
 2  | { title: 'Book 2', price: 11.5, author: { id: 2 } }
```

AUTHORS

```
 id | data
-----+-------------------------------------------------------
 1  | { name: 'Author 1', address: 'Address author 1' }
 2  | { name: 'Author 2', address: 'Address author 2' }
```

Is it possible to obtain this result, by merging the author key, with a JOIN-like statement or using jsonb functions?

BOOKS QUERY RESULT

```
 id | data
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | { title: 'Book 1', price: 10.5, author: { id: 2, name: 'Author 2', address: 'Address author 2'} }
 2  | { title: 'Book 2', price: 11.5, author: { id: 2, name: 'Author 2', address: 'Address author 2'} }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select b.data || jsonb_build_object('author', b.data->'author' || a.data)
from books b
join authors a on a.id = (b.data->'author'->>'id')::int;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7e331/1)

Comment: Wow so simple! Thanks!! what if authors is an array of author IDs, would it be still possible to merge with a simple query? (maybe this is another StackOverflow question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993341/merge-nested-array-of-jsonb-fields-with-a-join-like-statement-in-postgresql