# Merge nested ARRAY of JSONB fields with a JOIN-like statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, merge, nested, jsonb

Given this tables:

BOOKS

```
 id | data
----+-------------------------------------------------------
 1  | { title: 'Book 1', price: 10.5, authors: [{ id: 1}, { id: 2 }]}
 2  | { title: 'Book 2', price: 11.5, authors: [{ id: 2 } }
```

AUTHORS

```
 id | data
-----+-------------------------------------------------------
 1  | { name: 'Author 1', address: 'Address author 1' }
 2  | { name: 'Author 2', address: 'Address author 2' }
```

Is it possible to obtain this result, by merging the authors key array elements, with a JOIN-like statement or using jsonb functions?

BOOKS QUERY RESULT

```
 id | data
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | { title: 'Book 1', price: 10.5, authors: [{ id: 1, name: 'Author 1', address: 'Address author 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Author 2', address: 'Address author 2'}] }
 2  | { title: 'Book 2', price: 11.5, authors: [{ id: 2, name: 'Author 2', address: 'Address author 2'}] }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select b.data || jsonb_build_object('authors', jsonb_agg(a.data || 
jsonb_build_object('id', a.id)))
from books b
left join (select id, jsonb_array_elements(data->'authors') from books) ba on 
ba.id = b.id
left join authors a on a.id = ba.id
group by b.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The id arrays have to be unnested and results must be aggregated again what makes the query more complicated. I have changed a bit the arrays structure to more logical.

```
select b.data || jsonb_build_object('authors', jsonb_agg(a.data || jsonb_build_object('id', a.id)))
from books b
cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(b.data->'authors')
join authors a on a.id = value::int
group by b.id;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7de17/1)

Comment: Thanks again!! 
From your answer i managed to get the right answer for my specific case, in which I don't have control over nested "useless" id keys

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to do this but:

```
select
    book_id,
    jsonb_set(max(bdata :: text)::jsonb,
              '{authors}',
              jsonb_agg(nested.adata)) as author_data --aggregate authors into one jsonb arr
from (select
          b.id as book_id,
          b.data as bdata,
          a.data as adata
      from books b
      join authors a
          on b.data->'authors' @> concat('[{"id": ', a.id :: varchar, '}]') :: jsonb) as nested
group by book_id;
```

Relevant docs: see jsonb_set in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html and jsonb_agg at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html